# How do I get my chocolate mousse to be firm?

Tags: chocolate, mousse

I need to pipe my chocolate mousse into chocolate Cups but the shape is not staying, how do I make my Mousse firm? I used the following ingredients in my mousse: caramel treat, cocoa powder, chocolate and whipped cream.

Comment: What ratios are you using? Could you post the whole recipe, please?

Answer (score 2):

I always make my chocolate mousse with eggs, but two possible causes are that your ratios could be off or your chocolate mixture is hot and the whipped cream is cold, causing the mixture to seize-up and deflate.

If you decide to make a more traditional mousse, the ratio is very simple: 1 oz baking chocolate per egg.

Here is a basic recipe:

---

*Yields 4 servings*

- 4 oz baking chocolate
- 4 eggs (room temperature)

---

1. Separate the eggs
2. Melt chocolate over bain-marie
3. Whip whites until stiff peaks form
4. Whip yellows until off white and thick ribbons form
5. Whip yellows over bain-marie gently so they expand
6. Gently fold chocolate into yellows in small batches
7. Gently fold whites into mixture in small batches

It is critical that the eggs are room temperature, because cold eggs will make the chocolate seize up - this will make mixing more difficult and the whites will loose their fluff.

This is a very simple, classic method, but, if you're specifically looking to make the mousse egg-free, you can still use these techniques to help with yours.